# $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a differentiable and $f'(x) $ is bounded function then $f$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a differentiable function with $f(0) =0$. If for all $x \in \mathbb R , 1< f'(x) < 2$ then $f$ is unbounded.

We know that when $f'(x) > 0$ then $f$ is increasing and when $f'(x)$ is bounded then $f$ is uniformly continuous. From there how can we conclude that $f$ is unbounded??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f'(x) \ge \epsilon >0$ for all $x$, then $f$ is unbounded above.

The mean value theorem gives $f(x)-f(0) = f'(\xi)(x-0) \ge \epsilon x$, hence
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.

Comment: We meet again!  Looks like we're 8-0 on this one, old friend! ***Endorsed!***

Comment: @RobertLewis: :-)!

Comment: :-)! Backatcha!

Answer (score 1):

Or, using the fundamental theorem of calculus instead of the mean value theorem, we have, for $x \ge 0$, and any value of $f(0)$,

$f(x) - f(0) = \int_0^x f'(s) ds \ge \int_0^x (1) ds = (1)(x - 0) = x; \tag{1}$

thus

$f(x) \ge x + f(0) \to \infty \;\; \text{as} \; \;x \to \infty; \tag{2}$

and likewise, for $x \le 0$,

$f(0) - f(x) = \int_x^0 f'(s) ds \ge \int_x^0 (1) ds = (1)(0 - x) = -x; \tag{3}$

that is,

$f(0) -f(x) \ge -x, \tag{4}$

or

$f(x) \le x + f(0) \to -\infty \;\; \text{as} \;\; x \to  -\infty, \tag{5}$

showing $f(x)$ is unbounded in either direction.  ***QED!***

***NB:*** We observe, with copper.hat, that the assumption $f(x) \ge \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon  > 0$ is also sufficient to yield the same result.